# spring stored prod return values

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc

my stored prod returns a list of records, how do i handle the return values?
I tried using a rowmapper like in my jdbcTemplate.query methods but i can't get it to work.

```
public void executeClientSurveyProcedure(final Date startDate, final Date endDate) {
  List<SqlParameter> declaredParameters = new ArrayList<SqlParameter>();
  declaredParameters.add(new SqlParameter(Types.DATE));
  declaredParameters.add(new SqlParameter(Types.DATE));

  jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {
    public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
      CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call clientsurvey(?, ?)}");
      cs.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
      cs.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime()));
      return cs;
    }
  }, declaredParameters);

}
```

Comment: Which database software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure needs another parameter, an OUT parameter where you will receive a cursor to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass in the output variable where the return value will be stored. Or see this post on a similar question [How to call stored procedure to read return value and out parameter both in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911889/how-to-call-stored-procedure-to-read-return-value-and-out-parameter-both-in-sprin)